# Is there a possibility to render parts of the screen at lower resolution?

Tags: rendering, resolution, screen-resolution

I had this idea. In games especially we rarely use the endges of our screens but we use the center a lot more. Would it be possible to render a center circle or oval area at a higher resolution like 4k while the edges at a significantly lower. it probably would also improve VR performance most of all.

My question is, is this even possible? Did anyone try to do it?

I just want to know if it is possible at all. I am not very experienced in programming but it sounds like it would be beneficial.